# Using a library in php: class not found

Tags: php, namespaces, include

I'm trying to use this library: https://github.com/duzun/hQuery.php

My project is ordonated like this:

```
BetCompare
  Application
    Teams
      file_using_the_library.php
      hQueryLib
        hquery.php
```

So here is how I'm using it in my php file:

```
namespace BetCompare\Application\Teams;
use BetCompare\Application\Teams\hQueryLib\hquery;

hQuery::$cache_path = "/path/to/cache";
```

This returns an error `Class not found`. I've tried this after a few researches on the matter:

```
namespace BetCompare\Application\Teams;
use BetCompare\Application\Teams\hQueryLib\hquery;
include_once 'hQueryLib/hquery.php';

hQuery::$cache_path = "/path/to/cache";
```

Then the error is the following: `Cannot declare class hQuery_Context, because the name is already in use`. I don't understand, the second error makes it look like the `use` was enough and loaded the class. But I can't use it... What am I doing wrong?

I've also tried only using `include_once` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either like this (with namespace `duzun\hQuery`):

```
<?php

namespace BetCompare\Application\Teams;

use duzun\hQuery;

include_once 'hQueryLib/hquery.php';
hQuery::$cache_path = "/path/to/cache";
```

or like this, without the namespace:

```
<?php

namespace BetCompare\Application\Teams;

include_once 'hQueryLib/hquery.php';
\hQuery::$cache_path = "/path/to/cache";
```

---

Your code can not work, because if you write

```
use BetCompare\Application\Teams\hQueryLib\hQuery;
```

you are practically assuming, that the `hQuery` class has the namespace definition

```
namespace BetCompare\Application\Teams\hQueryLib;
```

which it does not have (beeing a third-party class).

The part with the `duzun\hQuery` is defined in the last lines of the `hQuery.php` file and described in the docus.

Comment: Oh I see, now it works! Thank you very much for the explanations.

Comment: You are welcome. Actually, If you read the additional text in the answer, you will discover that they provide a namespace for the class in a dynamical way, using `class_alias()`. Which is unfortunate, since you must have the docus beforehand, or know what those lines do.